add together the same core data item from multiple tableviews in UIKit
I have added a diagram below. What you can see in the diagram is a class where you save a food item. You click on the tableview cell and you can see a new class where you place the item and the amount you need to make that recipe. What I want to do is when you click on a tableview cell on the 2nd class. It searches throughout all the recipes to find the cumulative amount of that specific ingredient. In the diagram you can see that I highlighted apples. On the tableview cell it should be for example the apple hits 3.0, total all 8.0


import UIKit

class Ingriendentsx: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        specifcGame.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? CustomOneTableViewCell
        
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell") as? CustomOneTableViewCell
        }
        
        let expense = specifcGame[indexPath.row]
        
    
        
        
        
        
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(expense.name!) hits \(expense.amount)"
        
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    
    var txt = UITextField()
    var btn = UIButton()
    var tble = UITableView()
    var lbl = UILabel()
    var txt2 = UITextField()
    var backB = UIButton()
    
    
    
    var ingreidentsAndAmount = [Ingriendents]()
    
    var inital : Recipe?
    var placeholder = String()
    
    private var specifcGame : [Ingriendents] = []
    
    
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        
        if let budget = inital {
            lbl.text = budget.recipeName
            
            //
            
            if let aE = budget.ir?.allObjects as? [Ingriendents] {
                specifcGame = aE
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        [txt,btn, tble, lbl, txt2, backB].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
                
                textfield.textAlignment = .center
            }
            
            if let label = $0 as? UILabel {
                
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            }
            
        }//below
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            lbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0),
            lbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            
            txt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lbl.bottomAnchor),
            txt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0),
            txt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            txt.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            txt2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: txt.bottomAnchor),
            txt2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0),
            txt2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            txt2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: txt2.bottomAnchor),
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
            tble.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor),
            tble.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.50, constant: 0),
            tble.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            tble.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            backB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tble.bottomAnchor),
            backB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            backB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            backB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            
        ])
        tble.delegate = self
        tble.dataSource = self
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressA), for: .touchDown)
        tble.register(CustomOneTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        
        backB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backer), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    @objc func pressA(){
        guard let name = txt.text else {
            return
        }
        
        
        
        guard let calorieText = txt2.text, let count = Double(calorieText) else {
            return
        }

        
        guard let budget = inital else {
            return
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        let expense = DataManager.shared.saveToAttempts(name: name, amount: count, inz: budget)
        
        
        
        specifcGame.append(expense)
        
        tble.reloadData()
        DataManager.shared.save()
        txt.text = ""
        txt2.text = ""
        

    }
    
    @objc func backer(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    

}

class CustomOneTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
}


Sounds to me like you need to use an NSFetchRequest with a predicate (NSPredicate) to filter out all Ingredients that are Apple. Then you either need to loop over the result to get the sum or a more advanced solution where you use an NSExpression together with the fetch request that will calculate the sum for you directly

@JoakimDanielson can you show me in code?

func loadIngredients() has the logic for calculating total amount
class IngredientsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    struct IngredientDetail {
        let ingredient: Ingredient
        let totalAmount: Double
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var recipe: Recipe!
    var ingredientsDetail: [IngredientDetail] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
        loadIngredients()
        navigationItem.title = recipe.recipeName
    }
    
    func configureTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func loadIngredients() {
        let ingredientsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Ingredient>(entityName: "Ingredient")
        
        if var fetchedAllIngredients = try? PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(ingredientsFetchRequest) {
            
            // reset ingredientsDetail
            ingredientsDetail = []
            
            // filtering current recipe ingredients
            let recipeIngredients = fetchedAllIngredients.filter({ $0.recipe == recipe })
            
            for recipeIngredient in recipeIngredients {
                
                var totalAmount: Double = 0
                
                // name matching ingredients and calculating total amount
                // filtering to avoid rechecking matched ingredients
                fetchedAllIngredients = fetchedAllIngredients.filter({
                    if $0.name!.caseInsensitiveCompare(recipeIngredient.name!) == .orderedSame {
                        totalAmount += $0.amount
                        return false
                    }
                    return true
                })
                
                ingredientsDetail.append(
                    IngredientDetail(
                        ingredient: recipeIngredient,
                        totalAmount: totalAmount
                    )
                )
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func tappedAddIngredient() {
        if let ingredientName = name.text,
           !ingredientName.isEmpty,
           let amountText = amount.text,
           let amountDoubleValue = Double(amountText) {
            let ingredient = Ingredient(context: PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            ingredient.name = ingredientName
            ingredient.amount = amountDoubleValue
            ingredient.recipe = recipe
            PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
            loadIngredients()
            tableView.reloadData()
            name.text = ""
            amount.text = ""
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        ingredientsDetail.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        let ingredientDetail = ingredientsDetail[indexPath.row]
        if ingredientDetail.totalAmount > ingredientDetail.ingredient.amount {
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Name: \(ingredientDetail.ingredient.name!), Amount: \(ingredientDetail.ingredient.amount)")
            let boldAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)]
            let totalAmount = NSAttributedString(string: ", Total Amount: \(ingredientDetail.totalAmount)", attributes: boldAttributes)
            attributedText.append(totalAmount)
            content.attributedText = attributedText
        } else {
            content.text = "Name: \(ingredientDetail.ingredient.name!), Amount: \(ingredientDetail.ingredient.amount)"
        }
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        return cell
    }
}


Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer solves the issue. Please update your answer with some relevant explanation.

getting the error of Cannot find 'PersistenceController' in scope

@SamBurns please check the full code here. https://github.com/immanaro2497/RecipeApp
